# Posts are hiding under the Second Cell In CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, indexpath

i ma making Swift app with Xcode and using CollectionViewCell to fetch data from my WordPress Website. i have 2 cells in my CollectionView , one for loading posts and second for Google AdMob , I want to show Ads after 4 posts which is working great but now the problem is when Second cell is loaded i mean AdMob cell loaded then the post of that number is hidden behind it , like if there are posts of number 1,2,3,4,5 and ads load after 4 posts then number 5 post is no where.. this is my code

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
     if (indexPath.item % 5 == 1){
        
        let adcell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "adcell", for: indexPath) as! MovieCollectionViewCell
       
       // Google Ads Here
        
       return adcell
        
    }
    
    else{
        
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MovieCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MovieCollectionViewCell
        
        cell.setup(with: newsData[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}
```

please help me to solve this , i want to load ads but when ad loaded the post of that number should be loaded in next item cell.. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you use `indexPath.item` in the `if` block and `indexPath.row` in the `else` block, which might be a bit confusing but this is not the problem here.

`indexPath.item` is 4 on your fifth cell, so the `if` condition resolves to `true` and you return the `adcell`. On your sixth cell, `indexPath.row` is now 5, so the fifth item of `newsData` with index 4 is simply skipped.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if (indexPath.item % 5 == 4){
    
        let adcell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "adcell", for: indexPath) as! MovieCollectionViewCell
   
        // Google Ads Here
    
        return adcell
    
    }

    else {
    
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MovieCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MovieCollectionViewCell
    
        cell.setup(with: newsData[indexPath.item-(indexPath.item/5])
        return cell
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

If not already done:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return newsData.count + (newsData.count/5)
}
```

Comment: still did not work, still the post is skipped but the post number 5 is repeated now

Comment: i have replaced this if (indexPath.item % 5 == 1) with if (indexPath.item % 5 == 0) this , now only very first post is skipped, please can you help me to solve this too ? thanks

Comment: Try to replace `indexPath.item % 5 == 1` with `indexPath.item % 5 == 4`